# Every five seconds without refresh the new web page

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

How can I on a drupal site do a partial refresh of a page's content with AJAX every 5 second?

Answer (score 1):

Well it totally depends on what you want to refresh. I think what you are probably after though is [Block Refresh](http://drupal.org/project/block_refresh) which will allow you to refresh blocks every x seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's .load function to request the page and just return a part of it. See 'Loading Page Fragments' here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

You can specify a div id to be pulled and just replace that div on your current page. Run that using a setTimeout every 5000 milliseconds and you're there.

Not really a Drupal based solution. But should work.